# Specific alignment issues

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am setting up a school project its a gallery of pictures and I'm trying to get images to specifically align but I don't know how. Help.

I've tried basic align right, left and top but it doesn't work.

```html
<img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image" width="980" height="620">
<img src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" width="500" height="300" align="top">
<img src="https://northbridgecos.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sample4_l.jpg" width="500" height="300" align="right">
<!-- Line trying to fix -->
```

I want the 3rd Image to go under the 2nd image and I want the 3rd image to be the same size as 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

*align* is no longer supported in HTML5. In this specific case, the images should align correctly if you specify the units of `width` and `height` (e.g. `px`).

```html
<img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image" width="980px" height="620px">
<img src="https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" width="500px" height="300px">
<img src="https://northbridgecos.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/sample4_l.jpg" width="500px" height="300px"> <!-- Line trying to fix -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used `display:flex` to bring it on 1 line. below is the link.

https://jsfiddle.net/4rL7jnuc/1/`888`

if you need to check more about flex box then check below link. Thanks

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes